# Magento 2 (2.2) add custom tab for simple product only in admin

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, admin-panel

I want to ceate new configuration tab under product edit form admin for simple product only and save data to custom table.

I am using following scenario:

1- My/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">  
    <fieldset name="my_fieldset" class="My\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">More Product Links</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

2- My\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset.php

```
<?php  
namespace My\Module\Ui\Component\Form;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;  
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;  
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\FieldFactory;  
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset as BaseFieldset;

class Fieldset extends BaseFieldset  
{
    /**
     * @var FieldFactory
     */ 
    private $fieldFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        FieldFactory $fieldFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
        $this->fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get components
     *
     * @return UiComponentInterface[]
     */
    public function getChildComponents()
    {
        $fields = [
            [
                'label' => __('Field Label From Code'),
                'value' => __('Field Value From Code'),
                'formElement' => 'input',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('Another Field Label From Code'),
                'value' => __('Another Field Value From Code'),
                'formElement' => 'input',
            ],
            [
                'label' => __('Yet Another Field Label From Code'),
                'value' => __('Yet Another Field Value From Code'),
                'formElement' => 'input',
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($fields as $k => $fieldConfig) {
            $fieldInstance = $this->fieldFactory->create();
            $name = 'my_dynamic_field_' . $k;

            $fieldInstance->setData(
                [
                    'config' => $fieldConfig,
                    'name' => $name
                ]
            );

            $fieldInstance->prepare();
            $this->addComponent($name, $fieldInstance);
        }

        return parent::getChildComponents();
    }
}
```

This is showing on every product edit section but I want to show only for simple product.

Any help would be appreciated.